# Call direct image links from website for a function

Tags: javascript, imgur

Hi this is my code currently:

```
let images = [`t2EzsJj.png`,`TrRRE0v.png`,`vG8BkNG.png`,`uddMAhU.png`,`l9IpE9g.png`,`Lvv9S1s.png`,`od3robw.png`,`dl4HDpd.png`,`BJV4X1n.png`,`fC2HcsB.png`,`xtDuuGg.png`,`2VOBpXL.png`,`u3zKYpC.png`,`yymr6R8.png`,`cz8cZE0.png`,`rbYFSpp.png`,`zqAMDi9.png`,`Xmt84Qz.png`,`7wixIIK.png`,`Yfm3yGw.png`,`2DYKO6L.png`,`GrudZEl.png`,`OT115fy.png`,`k4bnBDa.png`,`tXTpcV8.png`,`PdkCufJ.png`,`NVaXfCV.png`,`5N69l7R.png`,`B2V8OKg.png`,`MOeIxJV.png`];
let intervalId = setInterval(function () {
  if (images.length === 0){
    clearInterval(IntervalId);
    return;
  }
  // this remove the first image from the array and return it
  let imageName = images.splice(0, 1); 
  sendChat(`/set 207 skinUrl https://i.imgur.com/${imageName}`)
}, 300)
```

All of the direct image links declared in 'imgaes' are from:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/useTv.jpg

I was wondering if there was a faster way to get the direct image links of all the direct image urls (in order) in the album?

As of right now I had to get the direct images 1 by 1, and I feel like there is a faster way since it took so long to get all the links.

Please let me know with coded examples.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Imgur has a REST API: https://apidocs.imgur.com/

On [this page](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#433753a1-04d4-1089-f022-cb65a33b9f3b) you can see how to get all images from an album.

Answer (score 0):

See the Imgur API.

> ```
> Album Images
> Return all of the images in the album
> Method    GET
> Route https://api.imgur.com/3/album/{id}/images
> Response Model    Image
> ```

At: [Imgur API - album](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/album#album)

TIP: Sites like Imgur usually have an API. Always search for an API instead **scraping** things manually from the HTML. If there is no API then a good idea would be to make **scraper**. If you prefer to use JS for that as well I would go with [**scraper** for NodeJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-scrapper).